# No gnome-power-manager command but it is installed on Arch

Tags: gnome, gnome3, power-management, fluxbox

I'm running latest Arch, have GNOME and Fluxbox and my main windows manager is Fluxbox. I wanted to manage my power settings in Fluxbox and i added gnome-power-manager in startup but is says there isn't a command like that. I checked if gnome-power-manager is installed with pacman and it says it is.
Note when i open power settings in GNOME shell environemnt there is no 'close lid' option.

**Note : Fixed** My main intention was to use this power manager to manipulate the laptop's state when i close the lid, press the shutdown button etc. I fixed this with instaling xfce4-power-manager.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome-power-manager as a stand-alone daemon/component no longer exists. Power management for the gnome-desktop now falls to gnome-settings-daemon, and as such, can't be easily imported into a non-gnome-desktop without pulling in a lot more than you would actually need. From what I can dig up; this happened around [3.2.1-1](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/g/gnome-power-manager/current/changelog#version3.2.1-1%203.2.1-1).